# Do spawners work in the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do spawners work in The Nether (top of nether)—especially Skeleton, Cave Spider, Zombie Pigman, and Zombie spawners?

Comment: What do you mean by work or anything in general?

Comment: I know this isn't a helpful answer, but you could use the Not Enough Items or Too Many Items mod, spawn in a creative world, go into the Nether, and try this for yourself. Just go into the Nether in the creative world, break the bedrock, place a spawner on top, and see what happens :).

Comment: @LeoKing You could also just use commands to give a spawned to you with custom NBT data.

Answer (score 6):

All spawners that normally work will work, so long as the conditions are met. For example, most animals need nearby grass, most hostiles need darkness, and all mobs need enough space to spawn.

Here is an image of zombies spawning in the nether from a spawner, which the other answer claims to be impossible:

[image]

Comment: @Noob, if this answers your question (and I think it fairly conclusively does,) you should accept it :).

Answer (score 5):

Only Mobs which can actually spawn on netherrack/brick will spawn. That means, skeleton, blaze, and zombie pigmen will spawn, but zombies and cave spiders wont.

The only mobs which can naturally spawn the nether are:

- Skeletons
- Zombie Pigmen
- Ghast
- Blaze
- Witherskeletons

Edit: The Nether still allows every kind of mob if you place the spawner on the correct block. For example, endermen will spawn if you place the block on endstone.

Comment: May I also add that Skeletons spawned in the nether will become wither skeletons?

Comment: No there are skeletons in the nether.

Comment: Does this include placing down dirt, stone, or other overworld blocks that these creatures can spawn on around the spawner?

Comment: There any many more mobs that can *exist* in the nether than what you've listed, however if you mean, 'spawn' rather than 'exist', then you aren't too far off. Magma Cubes being the omission that springs to mind.

Comment: @Bryan Actually, i talked about the natural Nether which isnt modified by the player. I am aware that you can even spawn the enderdragon if you place the spawner on endstone. I should have really used another word than exist.^^

Comment: @YUNOWORK You could also just summon it in like this without the spawner: `/summon EnderDragon`.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms I knoooow. That was just an example. :D You can do pretty much everything with the console.